# how to Calculate individual age based on Date of Birth

Tags: visualforce

how to Calculate individual age based on Date of Birth using formula fields
when i enter date of birth age must be updated

Comment: you have to take two fields by using roll-up summary you can calculate.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use any of the following

```
IF(MONTH(TODAY())>MONTH(Birthdate),YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(Birthdate),IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH(Birthdate),DAY(TODAY())>=DAY(Birthdate)),YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(Birthdate),(YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(Birthdate))-1))

FLOOR((TODAY() - DateofBirth__c)/365.2425)


TEXT(YEAR(TODAY() ) - YEAR( YOUR_DATE_OF_BIRTH_API ))
```

Comment: How about to add some explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

@Satya.

Create field:Age(Formulae data type).

In the formulae use: year(Today())-year(DOB__C)

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a formula for this recently, and it was a pretty painful endeavour. PS : I'm a newbie to Salesforce

The formula :

```text
IF( 
  NOT(ISBLANK(Birthdate)),
  TEXT(
    IF( 
      MONTH(Birthdate) < MONTH(TODAY()), 
      YEAR( TODAY()) - YEAR( Birthdate ),
      IF( 
        MONTH(TODAY()) = MONTH(Birthdate) && DAY(TODAY()) >= DAY(Birthdate),
        YEAR( TODAY()) - YEAR( Birthdate ),
        YEAR( TODAY()) - YEAR( Birthdate) - 1) 
      )
    ) & 
    " Years, " &
    TEXT(
      IF( 
        MONTH(Birthdate) <= MONTH(TODAY()), 
        IF( 
          DAY(Birthdate)<=DAY(TODAY()),
          MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(Birthdate), 
          IF(
            MONTH(TODAY())= MONTH(Birthdate),
            11,
            MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(Birthdate) - 1
          ) 
        ),
        IF(
          DAY(Birthdate)<=DAY(TODAY()),
          12-MONTH(Birthdate)+MONTH(TODAY()),
          12-MONTH(Birthdate)+MONTH(TODAY())-1
        ) 
      )
    ) & 
    " Months, " & 
    IF(
      MONTH(TODAY())=4,
      TEXT( 
        IF(
          DAY(Birthdate) <= DAY(TODAY()), 
          TODAY()-DATE(
                    YEAR(TODAY()),
                    MONTH(TODAY()),
                    DAY(Birthdate)
                  ), 
          TODAY()- ADDMONTHS(
                     DATE( 
                       YEAR(ADDMONTHS(TODAY(),-1)), 
                       MONTH(ADDMONTHS(TODAY(),-1)), 
                       DAY(Birthdate)
                     ),0
                   ) 
        ) 
      ),
      TEXT( 
        IF(
          DAY(Birthdate) <= DAY(TODAY()), 
          TODAY()-DATE(
                    YEAR(TODAY()),
                    MONTH(TODAY()),
                    DAY(Birthdate)
                  ), 
          TODAY()- ADDMONTHS(
                     DATE( 
                       YEAR(
                         ADDMONTHS(TODAY(),-2)
                       ), 
                       MONTH(
                         ADDMONTHS(TODAY(),-2)
                       ), 
                       DAY(Birthdate)
                     ),1
                   ) 
        ) 
      )
    ) & 
    ' Days', 
  ""
)
```

**For this to work you need to replace the `Birthdate` with your date field's name. This prints "X Years, X Months, X Days"**

[image: View on details page]

PS : The `TODAY()` Field on the layout isn't being used in the formula, But you can modify all `TODAY()` in the formula to calculate the difference between any two dates by making `Birthdate` as the smaller date and replacing `TODAY()` with the greater date